# How to convert an integer to string in clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

I am trying to set a :default-value for a input select dropdown.  If I hard-code a "2" it works.  If I pass in a 2 that I read out of a PostgreSQL database it fails.  I have tried (str ...) and (js/String ...) Nothing works.  I have no idea how to "inspect" the type.  I am passing these values to om-bootstrap.

```
    tech-id (utils/techid job cursor) 
    (i/input 
            {:type "select" 
             :default-value tech-id } 
            (d/option {:value "1"} "one") 
            (d/option {:value "2"} "two") 
            (d/option {:value "3"} "three") 
            (d/option {:value "4"} "four") )
```

If I manually set tech-id to be "2" it displays "two". Using the value from the database, it displays "one". I can even set it to 2 and it works.

Comment: `(str 2)` should work. Show code, how do you try to set defaults?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I think the first comment of (str 2) is correct and I was doing that.  The problem is in the life-cycle of the "input" component.  When I first create it, there isn't a value so it defaults to the first one in the list.  Later I display it without redrawing it, so it has the original "default-value".  I have to either find a way to "send" it a "select" message or re-draw it.

Comment: You should trigger render when you fetch new value from the database. The typical thing to do would be to get that value in will-mount and update the cursor, or have something fetch it elsewhere and update the cursor/put it on the core.async channel, etc. It's hard to say anything more without seeing the entire code for this component.